# Fractional Infinite Power Tower

Tags: calculus, exponentiation

I have been having fun with infinite power towers and I came across this problem:

> Let $a_2=\frac12$, and for $n>2$, $a_n=a_{n-1}^{\frac{1}{n}}$. Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$.

So I have absolutely no idea how to deal with the fractional exponents. I tried the standard power tower method where you assign it to a variable but I can't get anywhere with that. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This isn't a power tower, because the $a_{n-1}$ is not in the exponent in the recurrence equation.

Comment: @Karl Wouldn't it be $\frac{1}{2}^{\frac{1}{3}^{\frac{1}{4}^{\frac{1}{5}^{\cdots}}}}$ though?

Comment: No, for example: $a_5=(((\frac12)^\frac13)^\frac14)^\frac15=\frac12^{\frac13\times\frac14\times\frac15}\ne\frac12^{\frac13^{\frac14^\frac15}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have look at the first terms of the recurrence sequence to be able to understand the explicit expression of $a_n$:

$a_3=\frac{1}{2}^{\frac{1}{3}}=\frac{1}{4}^{\frac{1}{6}}$

$a_4=({\frac{1}{2}^{\frac{1}{3}}})^{\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{1}{4}^{\frac{1}{24}}$

$a_5=\{[({{\frac{1}{2}^{\frac{1}{3}}})]^{\frac{1}{4}}}\}^{\frac{1}{5}}=\frac{1}{4}^{\frac{1}{120}}$
.
.
.

$a_n=\frac{1}{4}^{\frac{1}{n!}}$.

So $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{4}^{\frac{1}{n!}}=1$ (since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n!}=0$).

Comment: See my comment on the question - you've solved the given recurrence equation, but the power tower expressions are wrong.

Comment: I have edited my answer...it was maybe  a matter of parenthesis?

Comment: I'm not quite sure it's incorrect - see wolfram: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%282%29%3D1%2F2%2C+f%28n%29%3Df%28n-1%29%5E1%2Fn

Comment: @AnayAggarwal yes I agree! Now it should works! You can check substituting the values for $n$